# How does PyCharm manage the PYTHONPATH when using Anaconda? Unable to find PySide2-related DLLs

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pyside2, shiboken2

I am extremely confused as to how PyCharm manages the path. I have failed to setup PySide2 both using `conda` and `pip`.

When installed with `conda` I get that the `shiboken2` DLL is missing. After a downgrade of PySide2 to a previous minor version it worked...Until I started PyCharm again.

When installed with `pip` I get that none of the PySide2 modules' DLLs can be found - `QtGui`, `QtCore`, `QtWidgets` etc.

I have verified the following:

- The interpreter used by my PyCharm project is set to the one from my Anaconda virtual environment
- The `<virtual-environment>/Lib/site-packages` is in the path for that interpreter (added by default)
- The DLLs are actually on the filesystem - the DLLs are clearly located in **Windows Explorer -> User files -> Anaconda3 -> envs ->  -> Lib -> site-packages -> PySide2 -> ...**
- The `sys.path` outputs the correct `PYTHONPATH`
- The run configuration points at the correct interpreter

I don't know where the `shiboken2` stuff is located so let's concentrate on the `pip` installation.

I printed the path

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and it matches.

---

**UPDATE:** Fixed the issue by installing PySide2 using `conda` and shiboken2 using `pip` with the version matching the one from `conda` (since `pip` has a more up-to-date version).

However this still doesn't answer my question. Even with PySide2 now working, I get problems in the PyCharm log regarding **ALL** imports like

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QDir
...
```

This indicates a path problem...again.